# How do you turn off browser suggestions on html input

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, autosuggest

How do you turn this off browser suggestions on html input?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use [`autocomplete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) on your inputs:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Something like:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

You can always switch back to `autocomplete="on"` when required.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Mozilla developer documentation the form element attribute autocomplete prevents form data from being cached in older browsers.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

> The password manager always prompts if it wants to save a password.
>   Passwords are not saved without permission from the user.
>
> We are the third browser to implement this change, after IE and
>   Chrome.